# How query to different tables in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can I output in my view the data orderBy latest?. I have to different tables the 'Assignments' & 'Posts' table. I want them to combine as one and output based on created_at field in the table.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried yourself. Don't get your work done by other users! SO is for helping with code not making the code.

Comment: I already tried to store them in an array but it is not working. I tried also putting a category but it is not working also.

Comment: Show your code... Whatever you have tried.

Comment: $posts = Post::all();
$assignments = Assignment::all();

$data = array($posts, $assignments);

sort($data);
But when I access the view with the variable $data it is not working

Comment: show your table structure and output you want.

Answer (score 0):

**You can output like this:**

```
$all = $posts->merge($assigments);
    $sorted = $all->sortBy('created_at');
    foreach ($sorted as $item) {
        echo $item->(your column name);
    }
```

Comment: How can I identify in the view if it is assignment or post so I can easily output the table name?